# How to get the oldest change applied by <username> in a git repo?

Tags: git

When working in WebStorm, I can see who changed the code in the open file by opening [revisions panel](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.2/working-with-annotations.html).
As I understand, this information is kept inside git and can be fetched.

So, I wonder, if it's possible to find the oldest change made by some username?
Are there tool to perform operations like history searching/filtering by username?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git log --author=user --reverse` will give you the list of commits by this user sorted from earliest to newest. See [git-log(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
git log --pretty='%ad %h' --author='<name>' --date=format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' <branch> | sort | head -1
```

If you want the commit date, use `%cd` instead of `%ad`. `--date=iso` might be okay.